# Iterable and Iterators - compile error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, iterable

I have the following interface:

```
public interface DataSet<T> extends Iterable<T>  {
  public int nExamples();
  public T getExample(int index);
  public Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

Then a class implementing this interface:

```
public class StringTupleDataset implements DataSet<StringTuple> {
Vector<StringTuple> examples;

public StringTupleDataset(Vector<StringTuple> examples) {
    if(examples == null) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null parameter: examples");
    this.examples = examples;
} // constructor

@Override
public int nExamples() {
    return examples.size();
} // nExamples

@Override
public StringTuple getExample(int index) {
    return examples.get(index);
} // getExample

@Override
public Iterator<StringTuple> iterator() {
    return examples.iterator();
} // getAllExamples
} // class
```

The class `StringTupleDataset` compiles with no problem.

However, when I try and write this piece of code in another class:

```
public abstract class AbstractOntologyFiller<T> {
private AbstractOntologyFiller() {}

public static <T> void fill(OntologyManager ontoManager, DataSet<T> dataset) {
     for(T e : dataset.iterator()) {
          // do something
     } // for
  } // fill  
} // class
```

I have a compilation error saying:

```
Can only interate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot iterate over an `Iterator`, but you can iterate through an `Iterable`.

```
for(T e : dataset)
```

will be enough, since `Dataset` extends `Iterable`, while `dataset.iterator` gives you an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate over `dataset` instead of `dataset.iterator()`

Explanation: the `for` loop is expecting an Iterable. The Iterable is not the iterator: it is the object that has the `iterator()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got the error.

I should have written:

```
public static <T> void fill(OntologyManager ontoManager, DataSet<T> dataset) {
    for(T e : dataset) { // (without .iterator()
```